# Problem: String writes over another string

Tags: c++, string, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to process two strings using the following code. The result works just fine but whenever I try to do the same operation for the second string, the first string gets written over by the second's value. for an example if the first string = "fuhg" and second string equals ="abc"  first string becomes: "abcg".
It probably has to do with memory allocation or something alike but I can't figure it out as I'm not very good in that area.

```
string newPassChar;
string newBloom=bloomFilter(newPass); 
int index=0;
for ( int k =0 ; k < alpha.length() ; k++ )
{
    if (newBloom[k]=='1')
      { 
        newPassChar[index]=alpha[k];
      index++;
      }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure `newBloom[k]`, `newPassChar[index]` and `alpha[k]` do not go out of bounds.  That said, please provide a [mcve] if you want help debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference std::basic_string::operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

```
No bounds checking is performed. If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined.
```

From [cppreference std::basic_string construcor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
1) Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and unspecified capacity).
```

So:

```
string newPassChar;
```

creates new string with `size() == 0`.

Then:

```
newPassChar[0] = ...
```

will overwrite the null character in the string. But on the next iteration, when `index = 1`, then:

```
newPassChar[1] = ....
```

it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). and spawns demons.

I think you want to "push_back" the characters as you read them:

```
        newPassChar.push_back(alpha[k]);
```

There no need to store another "index" variable used for indexing the string, the string object itself it knows it's size, it's available in `size()` method.

Comment: `pos == size()` is well-defined. Only modifying it is iffy.

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't read it clear, the cppreference said that for `pos == size()` the version `reference       operator[]( size_type pos );` was undefined behavior until C++11. Since C++11 it returns a reference to the null character, so it defined, there is the null character.

Comment: @KamilCuk note that since C++11, reading a `char` when `pos == size()` is well-defined behavior, but writing a `char` when `pos == size()` is still undefined behavior for any `char` value OTHER THAN `'\0'`. Presumably because the reference is to a static `char` located elsewhere in memory to stand in for a null terminator of empty strings.